# combine duplicates using pandas groupby().transform() with tolist() as aggregator

Tags: python, pandas

OK, so I want to invert a table with some duplicates:

    `ATC hierarchy               Drug Group
0      A                    Alimentary tract and metabolism
1    A01                        STOMATOLOGICAL PREPARATIONS
2   A01A                        STOMATOLOGICAL PREPARATIONS
3  A01AA                         Caries prophylactic agents
4  A01AB  Antiinfectives and antiseptics for local oral ...`

to get to something like this:

`Drug Group          allatcs
    0                    Alimentary tract and metabolism            ['A']
    1                        STOMATOLOGICAL PREPARATIONS  ['A01', 'A01A']
    3                         Caries prophylactic agents        ['A01AA']
    4  Antiinfectives and antiseptics for local oral ...        ['A01AB']`

So, the natural way is groupby() and transform(), but instead of using 'sum' or averaging as the tutorial examples, using tolist() on the series of the group values:

```
atcd_['allatcs'] = atcd_.groupby('Drug Group')['ATC hierarchy'].\
                          transform(lambda ser: ser.tolist())
```

But, alas, it doesn't yield the expected aggregation:

       `ATC hierarchy                                    Drug Group allatcs
0             A                    Alimentary tract and metabolism       A
1           A01                        STOMATOLOGICAL PREPARATIONS     A01
2          A01A                        STOMATOLOGICAL PREPARATIONS    A01A
3         A01AA                         Caries prophylactic agents   A01AA
4         A01AB  Antiinfectives and antiseptics for local oral ...   A01AB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too up on transform and how it is used, so I'm not sure why that is not working but what you want to do can be done quite easily with `.agg()`.

`atcd_.groupby('Drug Group')['ATC hierarchy'].agg(lambda ser: list(ser))`

Returns a series in the form that you want.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how to coerce "transform()" into doing it, but your way is obviously the easy way out..

Comment: On a personal note, whoaaa! it's my first question on stackoverflow and indeed it's quite a shock how fast an answer arrives, in this case before my own answer (which i started to type right after the question LOL :):) . Well maybe stack-overflow has a mechanism to prioritize answering first-timers, and pandas somehow got financing to keep a support dev on alert, but then it just makes it impressive in a slightly different way :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so 'transform' expects a function operating on a Series (representing a single Group), and return scalar OR a vector of same length as a series. The result is then "broadcast" on all the rows of the group, which means (A) putting the scalar value on all rows if output is scalar (B) "zipping" the vector elements to the group rows value-by-row if it's a vector.

The documentation is a bit misleading, explaining the vector case:

`"...Thus, the passed transform function should return a result that is the same size as the group chunk..."`

But then using the simple scalar case in all examples (e.g. ...transform('sum'))

Now if it's a vector, it's "broadcast" to all rows of the group it operates on.

So, what I should do is to return a scalar, which is a remarkably slight change:

```
atcd_['allatcs'] = atcd_.groupby('Drug Group')['ATC hierarchy'].\
                       transform(lambda ser: [ser.tolist()])
```

and now the desired result can be achieved via:

```
atcd_.drop('ATC hierarchy', axis=1).drop_duplicates(subset='Drug Group')
```

`Out[257]: 
                                              Drug Group      allatcs
    0                    Alimentary tract and metabolism          [A]
    1                        STOMATOLOGICAL PREPARATIONS  [A01, A01A]
    3                         Caries prophylactic agents      [A01AA]
    4  Antiinfectives and antiseptics for local oral ...      [A01AB]`